# Why is this function continuous on $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, real-numbers

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\mathbb R$ be a function with $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x+y) \le f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y \in \Bbb{R}$. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $0$, then $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$?

**THOUGHTS**:
I know the definition of $f$ being continuous at $0$, that is, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-0|<\delta$, 
$$
|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon\tag{1}
$$

But I don't know how to use (1) and the assumptions in the statement to show the continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, how would (1) be helpful for showing
$$
|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon
$$
for general $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$?

Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you tell us your definition of "$f$ is continuous at $x$"? There are at least two in common use, one of which involves $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s, and one of which involves limits.

Comment: Also: if your definition involves limits, have you encountered the "squeeze lemma" yet?

Comment: The continuous here involves  and , and I have not encountered squeeze lemma yet.

Comment: Intuitively "continuous" means a function has values $f(x),f(x+\delta)$ that are "close" whenever $\delta$ is "small".   The epsilon/delta definition of continuity makes this idea precise.  I get the sense that you are posting for Readers to "jump in" without making much effort to think the problem through for yourself, e.g. to see what $f(0)=1$ and the inequality require about $f(x+\delta)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h_n \to 0$ where $x \in \Bbb{R}$

Then

$f(x+h_n) \leq f(h_n)f(x)$ thus $\limsup_n f(x+h_n) \leq f(x)$

Now $$f(x)=f((x+h_n)-h_n) \leq f(-h_n)f(x+h_n)$$

Thus $f(x) \leq \liminf_n [f(-h_n)f(x+h_n)]=\liminf_nf(x +h_n)$

Combining the above we have:

> $$\liminf_n f(x+h_n) \leq \limsup_nf(x+h_n) \leq f(x) \leq \liminf_nf(x+h_n) \leq \limsup_n f(x+h_n)$$

Thus $\liminf_nf(x +h_n)=\limsup_nf(x +h_n)=f(x)$

So by the sequential characterization of limit(which is pressume you have learned) $$\lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h)=f(x)$$

Comment: I completely forgot the sequential characterization of limits/continuity when I made my comments. But to be honest, I'm doubting that OP is asking this question, in this way, and knows what "lim sup" means.

Comment: I am confused how to get lim sup f(x+hn) =< f(x). Could you please explain it? I know what is lim sup, and this is exactly my question. Thank you.

Comment: @DannyWen read the pink edit

Answer (score 0):

$f(x+h)-f(x)\le f(x)(f(h)-1)$. Moreover, replacing $x$ with $x+h$ and $y$ with $-h$ gives $f(x)\le f(x+h)f(-h)$ and thus
$$
f(x)-f(x+h)\le f(x+h)(f(-h)-1)\le f(x)f(h)(f(-h)-1).
$$
Thus,
$$
f(x)f(h)(1-f(-h))\,\le\,f(x+h)-f(x)\,\le\,f(x)(f(h)-1).
$$
Thus, if $f$ is continuous at zero, it is continuous at every $x$.

Comment: @Jack What do you mean? I don't see that the question is closed.